# Cannot execute .run file

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit, and I cannot execute .run files. I get a message saying that there is no application installed to open the file.

Answer (score 4):

You have to mark a binary as executable before you can run it. This is just a permission on a file so we use `chmod`:

```
chmod +x your_file.run
```

And then run it:

```
./your_file.run
```

Comment: And make sure you're not running it from a removable media.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful for beginner like me :D
And if the system say you need to be super user, type sudo ./your_file.run