# How to install programs downloaded from the internet?

Tags: software-installation

I've downloadad the latest [XAMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/postdownload?source=dlp) file, to install it into Ubuntu 13.04.

After downloading the file, I just can run it.

I've double click it (and I've tried right click and clicking "open", whith the same result).

All the answer I get is this message:

> Could not display “xampp-linux-1.8.3-1-installer.run”. There is no
> application installed for “executable” files. Do you want to search
> for an application to open this file?

I've tried searching for an application, with no result...

Also, I haven't found any questions related to this issue with the 13.04 Unity version...
I've tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66885/cannot-execute-run-file), with no result.

Please note that this isn't a Xampp question, the same happened to me when I tried to install Skype.

### UPDATE:

I've tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286491/how-to-install-a-program-ending-in-run-using-terminal):

> cd ~/Downloads
>
> chmod +x myfile.run
>
> sudo sh myfile.run

And I've got this error:

> Syntax error: "(" unexpected

What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with packaged software?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingRunPackage).  You need to change permission to allow executing, as mentioned in the link.  Then, open a `terminal`, navigate to the folder, and type `./xampp-linux...restofname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1** Move the .run to your Home folder

**Step 2** Right-click on the file and select Properties

**Step 3** Under the Permissions tab, tick the checkbox Allow executing file as program. Click Apply.

**Step 4** Double click the file to run

**OR**

Here is how to execute .run or .bin files

**Step 1:** Open the terminal and execute following command

```
$chmod +x file_name.run
```

**Step 2:** Execute the file

```
$./file_name.run
```

If you have any trouble or want to do it using GUI instead of terminal see this [link](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-execute-a-run-or-bin-file-in-ubuntu#.Umc7FXUW3Zg)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried both ways, and nothing happens.
In the command line way, it won do anything, it just acts as id I only pressed "enter". The GUI way, nothing happens, as if I didn't double clicked the file.